# Use trigger to filter certain date

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have a table called `COURSE` with these columns:

- `CourseId int`
- `CourseName varchar`
- `DateofStart Date`

I would like to create a trigger which ensures that courses cannot be run during August.

Comment: Please tag RDBMS name. SQL Server, MySQL.. ??

Answer (score 0):

Try this SQL code (for SQL Server)

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TRIGGER Tr_Course 
    ON Course
INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL() > 1
    RETURN

    UPDATE Course
       SET dateOfStart = I.dateOfStart
    FROM Course AS C
        JOIN INSERTED I ON C.courseID = I.courseID
    WHERE MONTH(I.dateOfStart) <> 8
END
GO
```

Comment: This is an assignment question, We must use trigger

Comment: So, in this situation use instead of trigger and in the body of trigger check your course date.

Comment: Yes, Thats the question, How can i do that? because i have no knowledge about triggers

Answer (score 0):

Check the examples given in this site for writing the trigger
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_triggers.htm#i1025109

step 1:  Since you need to check that courses cannot run during the august, you would be requiring a BEFORE INSERT trigger type.(Check the syntax in the link)

Step 2: Write the logic in Trigger body which will check the date that is being entered in the table

Step 3: If the DateofStart  is in august raise an exception or process accordingly

Do try and share the code snippet.

Answer (score -1):

```
create trigger check_month
on COURSE
for Insert
as
declare @Date nvarchar(10) 
declare @month int
select @Date=i.DateofStart from inserted i;     
set @month= (select DATEPART(MONTH,@Date))
if(@month=8)
begin
   Rollback
end
else
 begin
 commit
end
```

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is **not** the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `INSERT` statements affects 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once**, but then `Inserted` will contain 25 rows. WHich of those 25 rows will your code select here?? `SELECT @Date = i.DateofStart FROM Inserted i;` - it's non-deterministic - one get **one arbitrary row** and you ignore ALL OTHERS. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!

Comment: @MaryamMoeini: are you using MySQL?  Then you should **tag your question** accordingly!